# Why do some webpages have jerky rendering

Tags: css, html

Please see [this link](http://bit.ly/13XCntI). Notice that the search bar first renders near the top of screen. Then aligns itself to be opposite to the logo. I think some css rules are causing this but I am unable to figure out. Can you please help me in pinpointing the reason. What one should avoid in the code to avoid/minimize this behaviour.

Comment: I think StackOverflow just crashed your server.  Now you've got 2 problems.

Comment: @BillGregg It's the punishment for linking to your project :p

Comment: FWIW, when the page did come up in chrome, everything rendered at once.  In other words, it works on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This almost aways happens when you have a css rule for blocking that is overwriting the previous. The best thing to do is to have the first thing in the css file to be blocking and [normalizing](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/). Every time you need something to be in a place or have a specific size, you should go to the blocking section of your code.

But the most preocupying part of the site you shown is the time it takes to load a fancybox css file.

Answer (score 0):

This issue could just be how each browser loads and renders the content, and also on how fast your network can download content. Since there is many multiple Javascript and CSS files it can just be parsing them slowly and configuring the site as it goes while your network and browser is still downloading and loading everything.

I viewed it in Chrome and Firefox and it seemed to load fine for me.